# How to map xml objects into list<elements> in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml item tag which should be mapped into List. But while mapping apart from the list of item other elements has been mapped to the model.

I referred to other questions where each items is given a parent so they mapped while deserialising.

Let me know how to map to the given list item into the respective model.

XML:

```
<SecretModel>
    <id>3181</id>
    <name>Test</name>
    <secretTemplateId>6044</secretTemplateId>
    <folderId>674</folderId>
    <active>true</active>
    <items>
        <itemId>13960</itemId>
        <fileAttachmentId/>
        <filename/>
        <itemValue>Test</itemValue>
        <fieldId>287</fieldId>
        <fieldName>Username</fieldName>
        <slug>username</slug>
        <fieldDescription>The Amazon IAM username.</fieldDescription>
        <isFile>false</isFile>
        <isNotes>false</isNotes>
        <isPassword>false</isPassword>
    </items>
    <items>
        <itemId>13961</itemId>
        <fileAttachmentId/>
        <filename/>
        <itemValue>AKIAU5G4MQBA2TKQOWNW</itemValue>
        <fieldId>284</fieldId>
        <fieldName>Access Key</fieldName>
        <slug>access-key</slug>
        <fieldDescription>The Amazon IAM access key.</fieldDescription>
        <isFile>false</isFile>
        <isNotes>false</isNotes>
        <isPassword>false</isPassword>
    </items>
</secretModel>

SecretModel.cs:
   
   Public class SecretModel
   {
    public int? id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string SecretTemplateID {get; set;}
    public string folderId {get; set;}
    public string active {get; set;}
    public string List<RestSecretItem> {get; set;}
    }   
    
    
    public partial class RestSecretItem : IEquatable<RestSecretItem>
    { 
        
        public string FieldDescription { get; set; }

        public int? FieldId { get; set; }

        public string FieldName { get; set; }

        public int? FileAttachmentId { get; set; }
        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public bool? IsFile { get; set; }

        public bool? IsNotes { get; set; }

        public bool? IsPassword { get; set; }
        public int? ItemId { get; set; }

        public string ItemValue { get; set; }

        public string Slug { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to map xml, one is using built-in .NET XML serializer. Here is one way to serialize it.

**SecretModel**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SecretModel")]
public class SecretModel 
{
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "secretTemplateId")]
   public string SecretTemplateId { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "folderId")]
   public string FolderId { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "active")]
   public bool Active { get; set; }
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "items")]
   public List<RestSecretItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**RestSecretItem**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "items")]
public class RestSecretItem
{
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "itemId")]
   public int ItemId { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fileAttachmentId")]
   public int FileAttachmentId { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "filename")]
   public string FileName { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "itemValue")]
   public string ItemValue { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fieldId")]
   public int FieldId { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fieldName")]
   public string FieldName { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "slug")]
   public string Slug { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fieldDescription")]
   public string FieldDescription { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "isFile")]
   public bool IsFile { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "isNotes")]
   public bool IsNote { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "isPassword")]
   public bool IsPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can parse the xml through using this code:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.load("your directory or path of file here");
using(var reader = new StringReader(doc.InnerXml)) 
{
   var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SecretModel));
   var data = (SecretModel)serializer.Deserialize(reader); // converted model here
}
```